# Proving boundedness of the derivative of a univalent function. (Riemann Mapping theorem proof)

Tags: complex-analysis

In a proof of the Riemann Mapping theorem, we have a $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of univalent maps of an proper, non-empty, open, connected set, $\Omega$ into $B(0,1)$. I want to show that $$\rho=\sup_{n\to \infty}|f_n'(a)|$$ exists(i.e. it is finite) for $a\in \Omega$. Why is that the case? Can't seem to figure out

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of normal families?

Comment: @MartinR Montel's theorem is used in the very next step of the proof, so I doubt it has anything to do with that.

Comment: Why write "$\sup_{n\to \infty}|f_n'(a)|?$ Don't you mean $\sup_n?$

Answer (score 0):

Choose an $r > 0$ such that the disk $B(a, r)$ is contained in $\Omega$. Then apply the Schwarz Lemma to the functions 
$$
 g_n : B(0, 1) \to B(0, 1), g_n(z) = f_n(a+rz) \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 1 \ge |g_n'(0)| = |rf_n'(a)|
$$
and therefore
$$
\rho = \sup_n |f_n'(a)| \le \frac 1r \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose $r>0$ such that $\overline {D(a,r)}\subset \Omega.$ Then Cauchy says

$$f_n'(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{f_n(z)}{(z-a)^2}\,dz.$$

Now take absolute values, using $|f_n|\le 1$, to see $|f_n'(a)|\le \dfrac{1}{r}$ for all $n.$